# How to fix font on start page in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, fonts

I'm using Spacemacs on macOS. I installed [Hack Front](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Hack) and configged it in user-config of spacemacs:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Hack Nerd Font")
```

When I open the Emacs GUI [Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com), the start page like this:

[image]

When I open emacs in terminal, the start page like this:

[image]

It seems the `set-face-attribute` config doesn't work or is there another font necessary for the start window?

Comment: Your question is not clear: are you saying that the GUI image shows the start page as you expect and the terminal image differs from your expectation? Or are you saying that both are wrong (perhaps in different ways)? Saying that something "does not work" is not helpful: say instead what you expect and how the actual result differs from your expectation.

Comment: @NickD Use GUI start got the font issue. It doesn't matter in terminal.

Comment: Then why did you add the second image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> and run `all-the-icons-install-fonts` and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: It resolves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If can't show right font icons in Doom Emacs, run

```
M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts
```